# Magento Fatal error: Call to a member function setAddressFilter() in Address.php on line 431

Tags: magento, fatal-error, cart

I have this info after adding any product to cart (loged in or not loged in customers):
Fatal error: Call to a member function setAddressFilter() on a non-object in /home/we201626/public_html/xxx/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Address.php on line 431

I don't know what is the reason - I instaled AddThis extention but now I uninstal it and recover my data  - I had backup files. It doesn't work after it as well.

What happend?
How to resolve this problem?
Any idea?

Comment: it not be AddThis extension issue

Comment: I just ask AddThis and waiting for answer but why backup doesn't work?